# ESLint Unexpected Token {

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, eslint

As the title describes I am having an issue getting ESLint to run in my React project.

```
$ npx eslint **/*.js
Unexpected token {
```

package.json

```
    "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.0.0",
    "html-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  }
```

.eslintrc

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint"
}
```

Comment: your package.json looks like invalid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Your package.json should be an object

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.0.0",
    "html-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: I just posted the dependencies in package.json, not the entire file. It is an object in the project.

Comment: @RobBlinsinger your  "parser": "babel-eslint" is inside a parserOptions or not ?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [Installation and Usage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint#installation-and-usage) section of the npm package, there's a node.js version prerequisite for the eslint script to run.

You can check your node version by running `node --version`.

If you find you've got an unsupported node version, if figure you may consider switching to a higher node version or a lower eslint package version. E.g.: [eslint@6.8.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint/v/6.8.0)